# Android: how can I rotate image and set it filling fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that displays some images on 30% of the screen. In case when image.height is bigger than image.width, I wanted to rotate the image 90 degrees. However, after that operation, the image does not fully fill the fragment - "new" width after rotation matches previous height, so the image occupies only some part in the middle of the fragment. How can I make it a matching fragment? What I'm doing wrong or missing?

**This is how it looks like without rotation:**

[image: This is how it looks like without rotation:]

**This is after rotation:**

[image: This is after rotation:]

**And that's what I want to have:**

[image: And that's what I want to have:]

**Here is the code:**

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setImageFittedToDisplay(view);
    }


    public void setImageFittedToDisplay(View view)    {
        int height = getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = ((Double) (height * 0.3)).intValue();
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        int w = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        if(h > w) {
            image.setRotation(90f);
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageParams = image.getLayoutParams();
        imageParams.height = ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        imageParams.width = ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    }
```

and here is .xml of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/APOD_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cool_pic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorSeparator"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/picture"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picture" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml file holding the image.

Comment: Added .xml to therad. Unfortunately setScaleType() does not work - it increase height, so picture is square now and stretched

Comment: Try setting the image's height and width to match parent after rotating.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that - also tried, does not change anything